# How to change where the appsettings.json is searched for in WorkerService

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

**How can I change where the `appsettings.json` is searched for in a `.Net Core 3.1 Worker Service` project**

I've seen a few `Asp.Net Core 2.*` examples, but nothing for `3.1`.
Below is my `Program.cs` file. I know I need to change something here but I'm unsure what.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main( string[ ] args )
    {
        CreateHostBuilder( args ).Build( ).Run( );
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder( string[ ] args ) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder( args )
            .UseWindowsService( )
            .ConfigureServices( ( hostContext, services ) =>
             {
                 services.AddHostedService<Worker>( );
             } );
}
```

**Why I want this**

I need to containerize this application in to a `WindowsServerCore` container. The `appsettings.json` needs to be available and easily editable for technicians in the field.

I'm planning on `bind mounting` a directory with the `appsettings.json` from the host into the container. I'm unable to `bind mount` the directory into my applications `execution` directory as it will hide my `executable`. This means I need to `bind mount` into some other directory in the container (ex, C:\Configuration).

Because of this I want to change where the `framework` searches for my `appsettings.json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning**: I have not run the code snippet.

You can create a new instance of the `ConfigurationBuilder` directly instead of using `CreateDefaultBuilder`. The code would look something similar to below:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder( args )
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
                    (context, configurationBuilder) =>
                    {                        
                       configurationBuilder.SetBasePath("YOUR PATH")
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
                    })
            })
            .UseWindowsService( )
            .ConfigureServices( ( hostContext, services ) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>( );
            } );
```

Or else, instead of using `Default` settings you could also create your own `ConfigurationBuilder` from scratch as below:

```
public static IConfiguration CreateConfiguration()
{
    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .SetBasePath("YOUR PATH")
          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
          .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    return configurationBuilder.Build();
}
```

Comment: I used the first option you posted. Worked perfectly, thank you